# node.jsでconstが通らない

Tags: node.js

こちらのサイト(http://qiita.com/n0bisuke/items/350752978b16f4429b31) のソースをnode.jsで走らせたいのですが、エラーが出てしまいます。nodejsのバージョンは最新で'use strict'もついているのですが、他に注意すべきことがわかりません。どなたかアドバイスお願いします。

OS:mac
node:v0.11.11

```
/Users/ユーザー名/dir/trans.js:3
const http = require('http');
^^^^^
SyntaxError: Use of const in strict mode.
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:69:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:432:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:467:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:349:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:305:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:490:10)
    at startup (node.js:123:16)
    at node.js:1128:3
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Node.js のバージョンが古いので、6.0 以上に更新してください。

---

JavaScript に `const` や `let` が導入されたのは ECMAScript 2015 で、割と最近の話です。Node.js でこれがデフォルトで有効になったのは Node.js 4.x 以降です。

それでも独自実装のような形で使えはするのですが、 `use strict` を指定すると **ECMAScript 5 の** strict mode となり、かえって Syntax Error になってしまいます。

一応 `const` `let` に関しては、 `node --harmony app.js` といった感じに `--harmony` オプションを付けることで、当該機能を有効化することもできるようです。

参考 [javascript - SyntaxError: Use of const in strict mode - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23151062/2818869)

Answer (score 3):

リンク先のサンプルはnode v6.0で動くようになっていますが、質問を見る限りv0.11.11で動かそうとしています。

v0.11.11はv6.0と比べて古いバージョンです(バージョンの先頭の数字が0と6)

v6.0.0以上にnodeのバージョンをあげてください。

https://nodejs.org/download/release/v6.0.0/

上記のリンクはv6.0.0のダウンロードリンクです(v6.0.0は最新版ではありません)

https://nodejs.org/en/

最新版をインストールするには上のリンク先の数字が大きい方(先頭 -> 真ん中 -> 末尾の順番で比較する)をクリックしてください