# NodeSchoolでlearnyounodeの実行

Tags: node.js

[NodeSchool](https://nodeschool.io/ja/) で勉強をしようと思い、以下の記事を参考にセットアップしたのですが、`learnyounode` を実行すると以下の SyntaxError が出てしまいます。

実行した手順としては以下の通りです。

1. nvmをインストール (バージョンは0.25.4)
2. Node.jsをインストール (バージョンはv0.12.7)
3. `npm install -g learnyounode` を実行
4. `learnyounode` を実行するとエラー発生

なお、落としてきたファイルなどはいじっておらず、バージョンも記載されているままです。
他の手順が必要なのでしょうか？バージョンを更新しなければいけないのでしょうか？
何かご存知の方がいれば教えていただきたいです

**参考にした記事:**
[NodeSchoolでJS力をアップしよう！ - Qiita](https://qiita.com/kenfdev/items/277ce7a7310ac246b3b3)

**SyntaxError**

```
const explicit = require('explicit')
^^^^^
SyntaxError: Use of const in strict mode.
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:73:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:443:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
    at require (module.js:384:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/user/.nvm/versions/node/v0.12.7/lib/node_modules/learnyounode/node_modules/workshopper-adventure/index.js:2:20)
    at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
```

Answer (score 1):

Node.js のバージョンがとても古いです。参考になさっている Qiita の記事は 2015 年のもので、記事中で `nvm install 0.12.7` と書かれているのは 2015 年時点でのオススメバージョンです。2020 年の今、これでは古く、このため今回のエラーが起きています。エラーが起きている原因自体についてはこちらの Q&A をご覧ください：[node.jsでconstが通らない](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/29839/19110)。

この回答では解決法について説明します。

[learnyourcode のリポジトリ](https://github.com/workshopper/learnyounode)を見ても特に Node.js のバージョン指定は無いようですので、これから入門されるということであれば現在の安定バージョンを使えば良いように見えます。 https://nodejs.org/ja/ で LTS と指定されているバージョンの Node.js を使うようにしてみてください。この回答を書いている時点では、12.16.2 です。

nvm であれば、下のコマンドを使うことで安定版をインストールして使えるようにすることができます。インストール後、`node --version` でバージョンを確認してみてください。

```
nvm install stable --latest-npm
nvm alias default stable
```