# node.jsの開発環境を作りたいのですが、不足しているリソースの導入方法がわかりません

Tags: node.js

以下のリンク
https://qiita.com/tarotaro1129/items/93521afd693796eb2cfa
のソースコード

```
'use strict';
//モジュールの読み込み
const fs = require('fs');
const readline = require('readline');

//readstreamを作成
const rs = fs.createReadStream('./input.csv');
//writestreamを作成
const ws = fs.createWriteStream('./output.csv');

//インターフェースの設定
const rl = readline.createInterface({
//読み込みたいストリームの設定
  input: rs,
//書き出したいストリームの設定
  output: ws
});

//1行ずつ読み込む設定
rl.on('line', (lineString) => {
  //wsに一行ずつ書き込む
  ws.write(lineString + '\n');
});
rl.on('close', () => {
  console.log("END!");
});
```

こちらを実行すると以下のようなエラーが出ます。

```
const fs = require('fs');
^^^^^
SyntaxError: Use of const in strict mode.
    at Module._compile (module.js:439:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:902:3
```

別のサーバでは動作確認できたのですが、開発環境にしたいサーバでエラーが出ます。
どのような問題が起きていると予想できますでしょうか？

Comment: 次の投稿はあなたの質問の回答になりますか？ [node.jsでconstが通らない](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/29839/node-js%e3%81%a7const%e3%81%8c%e9%80%9a%e3%82%89%e3%81%aa%e3%81%84)

Comment: 上のコメントとは違うというのであれば、エラーが起きる環境の情報(OSやNode.jsのバージョン、Node.jsをどのようにしてインストールしたか)を質問に追記して下さい。